# Node.js/SignalR Communication

Tags: node.js, websocket, signalr

I got a server running SignalR and another server runing Node.js. I would like these two servers to communicate using SignalR. Is this possible?

I'm thinking I can use the SignalR client javascript library to connect to the SignalR server from Node:js but I can't find any good examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well the answer to *can* you do this is ultimately "yes" because there is nothing proprietary about SignalR communication. It's just variations of HTTP or WebSockets with a custom handshake/message framing protocol for Hubs on top of that.

So the *how* is the question we'd need to answer. Out of the box SignalR provides a client side JavaScript library based on the jQuery plug-in architecture, but that won't help Node.js. Someone has started a Node.js implementation [here on GitHub](https://github.com/maartenba/SignalR.Node), but according to the ReadMe it only supports HTTP long polling today. I'm unaware of any other implementations at this time, but obviously you start with that one and fork it to add support for the other transports if you wanted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answert. Maybe I add the websocket transport :)